# which of the following are linear mappings?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following mappings are linear?

(a)$\varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}, \varphi(x) = (1 - x, (1 - x)^{2}),$

(b)$\varphi : \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \varphi(f) = f(1),$

(c)$\varphi : \mathbb{R}[t] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[t], \varphi(f) = t \cdot f', $

(d)Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-Vectorspace of converging sequences $(a_{n})$ of real numbers. Let $\varphi \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \varphi((a_{n})) = a^{3}_{1} +$ lim $a_{n}.$

Comment: @user3711: what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT:** A mapping is said to be linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(ax)=af(x)$.

Verify whether the maps which you have given satisfy the above 2 conditions. If they satisfy then conclude that the map is linear. A simple example would be to consider $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi(x)=cx$, note that $\varphi(x+y)=c(x+y)=cx+cy=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$ and $\varphi(ax)= a(cx)=a \varphi(x)$. Hence $\varphi$ is a linear map. With this example in mind, proceed for your question.

Comment: Hmm so if I understand that correctly (a) is clearly not a linear mapping since: $\varphi(x+y)=(1-x-y,(1-x-y)^{2})\neq(2-x-y,(1-x)^{2}+(1-y)^{2})=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$
is that correct?

Comment: with (b) i'm not sure if i totally understand the concept, is it that the function of a function is equalto the function's value at one? in this case i would like to simply write $\varphi(f+g)=(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=\varphi(f)+\varphi(g) and \lambda\varphi(f) = \lambda f(1) = \varphi(\lambda f) \Rightarrow$ (b) is a linear mapping??

Comment: p.s i really appreciate that you responded so thoughfully and quickly :)

Comment: Yes, that is the correct interpretation of (b).

Comment: ok cool so (b) is taken care of.. does that mean i got (a) wrong? any other clues for (c) and (d)? i am still having difficulty understanding them

Comment: or for (a) would it simply be enough to say that since $\varphi(0) \neq 0$ it does not satisfy the condition of scalar multiplication and is therefore not a linear map?

Comment: @user3711: You are right, a linear map must send 0 to 0.  But your first answer is fine, too.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: I actually disagree; I would not find the written statement sufficient for a proof that $\varphi$ is not additive. Just because two expressions don't look the same does not mean they don't evaluate to the same. I would require that he either exhibit specific values of $x$ and $y$ for which the two expressions are different, or else he show that the two expressions *cannot* be equal (in this case, $1-x-y$ can never equal $2-x-y$, but it needs to be said).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: I see your point, which you made very clear below (and I upvoted).  It seemed acceptable to me without the specific statement as they are clearly different by 1.  As you say, in other cases it is not so clear, and showing a specific failure is a good way to think about the difference of proving for all x ...   and not for all x ...

Answer (score 4):

To amplify Chandru1's response, it is important to note the difference in how we check that a map is linear and how we check that a map is *not* linear.

In order to show that a map $\varphi$ is linear, we need to show that **for every** $\mathbf{x}$ and **every** $\mathbf{y}$ $\varphi(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})=\varphi(\mathbf{x})+\varphi(\mathbf{y})$; and that **for every** scalar $\alpha$ and **every** $\mathbf{x}$, we have $\varphi(\alpha\mathbf{x})=\alpha\varphi(\mathbf{x})$. This is often done at the level of "general formulas", checking that both expressions in each case lead to *identical* formulas. Thus, for example, to check that you function (b) is a linear transformation, we verify that both $\varphi(f+g)$ and $\varphi(f)+\varphi(g)$ lead to the same expression:
$$\varphi(f+g) = (f+g)(1) = f(1)+g(1);\qquad \varphi(f)+\varphi(g) = f(1)+g(1);$$
and likewise with $\varphi(af)$ and $a\varphi(f)$:
$$\varphi(af) = (af)(1) = a\cdot f(1);\qquad a\varphi(f) = a\cdot f(1).$$

**However**, what you write in your comment for (a) is *not* a good proof that the map $\varphi(x) = \bigl(1-x, (1-x)^2\bigr)$ is not linear. When you write something like:
$$ \varphi(x+y) = \bigl( 1-x-y, (1-x-y)^2\bigr) \neq (2 - x -y, (1-x)^2+(1-y)^2\bigr) = \varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$$
you are actually asserting that the two expressions as **never equal**. But in many instances, students will write this even when the expressions may sometimes be equal, yet think this constitutes a proof that the map is not linear.

This is *not* the case. You must either explain why the two expressions *actually* are never equal (this happens in this case, because $1-x-y$ is never equal to $2-x-y$), or you must exhibit specific values of $x$ and $y$ for which the two expressions evaluate to different values. It is *not* enough for the formulas to "look different".

In order to show that the function is not linear, you must show that there exist **specific** $x$ and $y$ such that $\varphi(x+y)$ is not equal to $\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$, or that there exist a **specific** $\alpha$ and a **specific** $x$ such that $\varphi(\alpha x)\neq \alpha\varphi(x)$. That is, the verification that the equality does not always hold is *not* done at the level of "the formulas don't look the same", but rather by saying: *"here are specific values, and, look, they don't match"*. So to show that (a) is *not* linear, rather than working out the expressions and seeing that they don't *seem* to be identical (just because two things don't *look* identical doesn't mean they don't always take the same value; "$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$" looks very different from "$1$", but they always take the same value), you should find *specific* values of $x$ and $y$ for which the answers don't come out the same. For instance, you could show that if $x=y=1$, then
$$\varphi(1+1) = \varphi(2) = \bigl( 1-2, (1-2)^2\bigr) = (-1,1),$$
but 
$$\varphi(1)+\varphi(1) = \bigl( 1-1, (1-1)^2\bigr) + \bigl(1-1, (1-1)^2\bigr) = (0,0)+(0,0)=(0,0),$$
and since $(-1,1)\neq (0,0)$, then $\varphi(1+1)\neq\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)$. *This* shows the map is not linear, not the fact that the formulas for $\varphi(x+y)$ and for $\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$ don't seem to be identical.

Think about it this way: to show that not every student in your class has red hair, it is not enough to argue that it would be highly unlikely that everyone in a big class would have such an uncommon color of hair, that it never happens, that it doesn't look that way when one takes a quick look, etc. The *sure* way of showing that not every student in your class has red hair is to stand someone up and *show* that he/she does not have red hair, and then you're absolutely done.

The same is true for (d).

Comment: right, that absolutely makes sense to me. i think the only thing i'm still not understanding is how to interpret (c) and (d) (without even trying to test if they are linear). i wasn't sure if the brackets around $t$ meant something in particular and i need to do some reviewing/learning of converging sequences, limits, etc... Thanks a lot for the response!

Comment: @user3711: The brackets in (c) are part of the notation. It means your vector space is the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ with indeterminate `t`. In (d), each vector is really a sequence of real numbers, which you can think of as an "infinite tuple".